# Post in the wall of a follower

Tags: c#, linq-to-twitter

How to update status of a specific user on twitter using LinqToTwitter
I tried this :

```
 twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);

 twitterCtx.UpdateStatus("Welcom  " + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "userId");
```

the probleme is that update status of all my followers

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean sending a direct message to another twitter user?

[This](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sending%20Direct%20Messages&referringTitle=Working%20with%20Direct%20Messages) describes how to send a direct message:

```
var message = twitterCtx.NewDirectMessage("16761255", "Direct Message Test - " 
                                      + DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: not a direct message, Updating Status of twitter user. this methode  twitterCtx.UpdateStatus("Welcom  " + DateTime.Now.ToString()) update satatus of all my follower, i want to specify which user to update his status

Comment: Twitter don't has a features to add a status update to another users account, you can only add one in your own account. Other options are: Write @accountname or a direct message.

Comment: twitterCtx.UpdateStatus("Welcome" + DateTime.Now.ToString()) send a tweet to a twitter user, all follower of this user can show this tweet,

Comment: A direct message is not visible to other users, but isn't what you are looking for?

Comment: I do not want sending a direct message I will rather send a tweet to a Twitter user who will be viewed by all his followers, thanks